# Connecting to neo4j-graphql websocket for subscriptions?

Tags: neo4j, websocket, graphql, graphql-subscriptions

I haven't found any information on how to connect to a websocket to enable graphql subscriptions on a neo4j (3.3) instance with the `neo4j-graphql` plugin installed.

I've also unsuccessfully tried urls relating to the bolt port (localhost:7687).

Is this possible to do?

If not, could there be a workaround at the level of a separate, subscription-enabled graphql server when using schema delegation down to the neo4j server?

Answer (score 0):

So, neo4j-graphql doesn't implement ws [yet](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql/issues/94)

And yes, if calling the db through a graphql server such as aws appsync that would enable subscriptions.